# Bootstrap css overriding FullCalendar css even if the fullcalendar.css is placed after bootstrap.css in header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

my bootstrap.css file is overriding the fullcalendar.css file even if I correctly place there order in the header:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='calendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='calendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet'media='print'/>
</head>
```

Normally, fullcalendar.css should override the bootstrap.css file but it's not working.
Some text are smaller and underlined when I insert the bootstrap.css file in the header and I don't want that. I can set all the lines in the fullcalendar.css file as !important but the fullcalendar.css contain a lot of line and I am not sure if this solution will work.Please help.

Comment: without seeing the content of fullcalendar.css and some of your html, it's difficult to say what it is, but chances are that fullcalendar.css doesn't cover everything bootstrap.min.css does, or (very basic) fullcalendar.css might not be found...

Answer (score 0):

It should be too late but my answer may get help to others.

For bootstrap 5, You can refer to [fullcalendar official demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap5-demo) to overwrite the css styles

add `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/bootstrap5@6.0.2/index.global.min.js"></script>`  after bootstrap 5 css links can help to fix the problem.